# What causes SSL certificate verification to be required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, ssl-certificate

I recently started receiving this error when sending requests to a third-party API.

```
  def api_call
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    request.body = request_body.to_json
    request.content_type = 'application/json'
    https.request(request)
  end
```

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed`

I know adding `http.ca_file = '/path/ca_file'` to the request would fix it, but my question is what would have changed to make the verification required? Is there a certificate configuration or extension that forces the sender to verify the certificate?

Comment: Did your target URI endpoint recently updated its certificate?  Check to ensure the cert is valid and trusted, and verify that your /path/ca_file contains the issuer CA.  Finally, check your environment (path) and configuration files.  Software and OS updates can mess with your environment, and potentially reset configuration files.  It's possible that your runtime environment previously had access to find /path/ca_file, but now it doesn't.  Just some thoughts.

Comment: @leeharvey1 yes, the target recently updated their cert with Let's Encrypt. It seems to be caused by a Ruby docker image that is no longer supported - ruby:2.4-alpine. When building with a supported image (https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/ruby), the request worked and did not require the cert to be verified.

Comment: Cause: https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/. The ruby:2.4-alpine image uses OpenSSL 1.0.2.